# Application Insights: Logs not streaming when deployed to App Service But streams in local debug environment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-3.1

**What I am trying to achieve**

Hello, I have dotnetcore web Api which is running in Azure App Service server farm. For logging I have used both ILogger and Log4net. I am trying to send the logs of service to application-insights but the logs are not streaming when deployed to Azure but when tested locally it works fine and I can see logs from both the library ILogger/Log4net getting streamed to Application Insights.

**What I have tried so far**

Below configuration I have added in my service for application insights.

- Runtime version: netcoreapp3.1 version-2.31.0.1
- Hosting environment: Azure App Service

**app-service.csproj**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender" Version="2.20.0" />
    ...
<ItemGroup>
```

**log4net.config**

```
<appender name="aiAppender" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender.ApplicationInsightsAppender, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender">
  <InstrumentationKey name="AppInsightsKey" value="abcdefgh-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcdefghijkl" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

**startup.cs**

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Logger.ConfigureLog4Net("./logs/app.log", Configuration)
            ...
        }
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // The following line enables Application Insights telemetry collection.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(
                new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
                {
                    EnableActiveTelemetryConfigurationSetup = true,
                    InstrumentationKey = Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"] 
                }) ;
            services.AddMvc();
            ...
        }
```

**appsettings.json**

```
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "xxxxx"
  }
```

I have also added `ApplicationInsights.config` file as suggested in elsewhere for Log4net to work as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
    <InstrumentationKey>xxxxx</InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

I have also added the key `ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey` in App Service Configuration App Settings. As well tried with default app settings key `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`.

I have made sure all the required App settings keys are present in App service configuration too.

Followed this MS document on [common issues Troubleshooting Application Insights Agent (formerly named Status Monitor v2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/status-monitor-v2-troubleshoot) and as it quotes below

> If any of these DLLs are present in the bin directory, monitoring
> might fail:
>
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll

> Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.dll

> System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll

But it's really confusing cause the required Nugets like "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" has "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll" as dependency which in-turn has "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll" as dependency; and without the required AspNetCore nuget Application Insight won't work.

Essentially, this is a strange issue am facing where-in all logs and exceptions getting streamed perfectly fine in local run but once deployed to Azure App service no logs are streaming at all. Can someone shed some light here? Am I missing something obvious??

Comment: The version you are using for `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` and `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender` is Deprecated.
Try with the latest version and check once.
[Image1](https://i.imgur.com/ZdXrMD9.png)
[Image2](https://i.imgur.com/635fK1B.png)

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT Thank You but that's a typo while posting the question. I am using 2.20.0 version which is latest. Edited the post .. sorry for confusuon

Comment: As per that document I have deleted the ***System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll*** from the bin folder and tried to build the application, I didn't got any errors. After deleting the dlls from bin ,deploy the application once and check the logs.

Answer (score 0):

- There are 5 Nuget packages that depend on`System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll`  , which belongs to logging of data.
- This particular dll produces more conflicts while logging ApplicationInsights data.
- Delete the `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll` from the bin folder ,build and deploy the application once and check the logs in Portal.
- As it is a Default template added with the
  `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` , I didn't found any build issues after deleting it from bin.
- Here is the [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66443919/application-insights-stops-working-after-deployment-to-azure-app-service) which cleared the same issue.

Comment: Hello Harshitha, Thanks again for your suggestion but this dll can't be the issue here at all. Cause, those dll would cause trouble for codeless instrumentation approach but for me app insights instrumentation have been done through SDK. Moreover, if you have checked, the required dll's of `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` itself has dependency on `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll`. This could be a pretty helpful answer for someone else in future following codeless approach but for me this doesn't help really. sorry.

Comment: @Rahul - Any update for the issue ?

Comment: Appreciate for checking Harshitha. I am working with Azure Support Team on this .. over a support ticket

Comment: Any update for now?